# How to solve Fatal error: Cannot redeclare view() (previously declared? (phpunit laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.3

When I run `./vendor/bin/phpunit` to check my event & listener, there exist error like this :

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare view() (previously declared in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php:850)
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\app\Http\helpers.php on line 92 PHP Fatal
>   error:  Cannot redeclare view() (previously declared in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php:850)
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\app\Http\helpers.php on line 92

How can I solve it?

Comment: please mention controller code also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this code

```
 if (!function_exists('view')) {
    function view()
    {
        //your code here
    }
    }
```

or you can use

```
include_once() or require_once() // your file where you include , so change it and replace it hope it will work
```